# Can we get the expression for this integral without expansion?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

The integral is
$$
\int_{\theta_L}^{\theta_H} \frac{1}{y} \cdot (\theta_H-y)^{N-1} dy,
$$
where $\theta_H>2>\theta_L \geq 1$ and $N \in \mathbb{N}$.

Is there any convenient way to calculate this without expansion? Also, I am interested in
$$
\frac{N}{(\theta_H-\theta_L)^N} \cdot \int_{\theta_L}^{\theta_H} \frac{1}{y} \cdot (\theta_H-y)^{N-1} dy
$$
when $N \rightarrow \infty$. Does it converge to $0$?

Comment: No problem using the Gausian hypergeometric function

Comment: Thank you so much! Shall I use this one?
$$
\mathrm{B}(b, c-b){ }_2 F_1(a, b ; c ; z)=\int_0^1 x^{b-1}(1-x)^{c-b-1}(1-z x)^{-a} d x \quad \Re(c)>\Re(b)>0
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $N\to\infty$, use the substitution $t = \left(\frac{\theta_H-y}{\theta_H-\theta_L}\right)^N$

$$L = \lim_{N\to\infty} \int_0^1 \frac{dt}{\theta_H - (\theta_H-\theta_L)t^{\frac{1}{N}}} \longrightarrow \int_0^1 \frac{dt}{\theta_L} = \frac{1}{\theta_L}$$

by dominated convergence.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I tried to rewrite it in my setting,
\begin{align*}
&\frac{N-1}{(\theta_H-\theta_L)^N} \cdot \int_{\tau}^{\theta_H} \frac{(\theta_H-y)^{N-1}}{y} dy\\
=&\frac{N-1}{\theta_H-\theta_L} \int_{\left(\frac{\theta_H-\tau}{\theta_H-\theta_L}\right)^{N-1}}^{0} \frac{t}{\theta_H-t^{\frac{1}{N-1}} \cdot (\theta_H-\theta_L)} d\left(\theta_H-t^{\frac{1}{N-1}} \cdot (\theta_H-\theta_L)\right)\\
=&\int_{0}^{\left(\frac{\theta_H-\tau}{\theta_H-\theta_L}\right)^{N-1}} \frac{1}{\theta_H \cdot t^{-\frac{1}{N-1}}-(\theta_H-\theta_L)} dt
\end{align*}
which is a little bit (TBC)

Comment: different. Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: @cxxu96 yes your first mistake was using the substitution to $N-1$ power instead of $N$ power. Also you missed the factor $\theta_H - \theta_L$ inside of the substitution. Also why is your lower bound $\tau$ instead of $\theta_L$ ?

Comment: I see. If $\tau=\theta_L$, the integration will be from $0$ to $1$. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int \frac{ (\theta_H-y)^{n-1}}{y}\, dy=\big[\theta_H\big]^{n-1}\int\frac{ (1-x)^{n-1}}{x}\, dx$$
$$J=\int\frac{ (1-x)^{n-1}}{x}\, dx=-\frac{(1-x)^n }{n}\, _2F_1(1,n;n+1;1-x)$$
$$K=\int_a^1\frac{ (1-x)^{n-1}}{x}\, dx=\frac{(1-a)^n }{n}\, _2F_1(1,n;n+1;1-a)=B_{1-a}(n,0)$$